# Why cant recieve data from nested model on a query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I have a nested model package.rb:

**Routes:**

```
resources :clients do
    resources :packages
end
```

I want to make a query in this model, so I have this on my Package model:

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  # Search
  def self.search(search)
  key = "%#{search}%"
    if search
      where(["entry_packet LIKE :search OR outbound_packet LIKE :search OR package_dimentions LIKE :search OR package_weight LIKE :search OR delivered_package LIKE :search OR safeguard_time LIKE :search OR batch_number LIKE :search OR barcode_packet LIKE :search", search: key])
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

**Controller packages_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @packages = @client.packages.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 6).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

**In my view I have this:**

```
<!-- Search -->
<div class="row search">
  <div class="col-xs-12 pull-right">
    <%= form_tag client_packages_path, :method => "get" do %>
    <p>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search packages" %>
    </p>
    <p class="pull-right">
      <%= submit_tag "Search", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ./Search -->
```

**Rake Routes:**

```
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                     Controller#Action
                root GET    /                                               dashboard#index
     dashboard_index GET    /dashboard/index(.:format)                      dashboard#index
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                        devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                        devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                       devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                   devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                  devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#update
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)                       devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                         devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                        devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                           devise/registrations#edit
                     PATCH  /users(.:format)                                devise/registrations#update
                     PUT    /users(.:format)                                devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)                                devise/registrations#destroy
     client_packages GET    /clients/:client_id/packages(.:format)          packages#index
                     POST   /clients/:client_id/packages(.:format)          packages#create
  new_client_package GET    /clients/:client_id/packages/new(.:format)      packages#new
 edit_client_package GET    /clients/:client_id/packages/:id/edit(.:format) packages#edit
      client_package GET    /clients/:client_id/packages/:id(.:format)      packages#show
                     PATCH  /clients/:client_id/packages/:id(.:format)      packages#update
                     PUT    /clients/:client_id/packages/:id(.:format)      packages#update
                     DELETE /clients/:client_id/packages/:id(.:format)      packages#destroy
             clients GET    /clients(.:format)                              clients#index
                     POST   /clients(.:format)                              clients#create
          new_client GET    /clients/new(.:format)                          clients#new
         edit_client GET    /clients/:id/edit(.:format)                     clients#edit
              client GET    /clients/:id(.:format)                          clients#show
                     PATCH  /clients/:id(.:format)                          clients#update
                     PUT    /clients/:id(.:format)                          clients#update
                     DELETE /clients/:id(.:format)                          clients#destroy
```

I recive this on **server log**:

```
Started GET "/clients/1/packages?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=15&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-28 15:08:29 -0500
Processing by PackagesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"15", "commit"=>"Search", "client_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Client Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `clients`.* FROM `clients` WHERE `clients`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered packages/_search.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Package Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `packages`.* FROM `packages` WHERE `packages`.`client_id` = 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `packages` WHERE `packages`.`client_id` = 1 AND (entry_packet LIKE '%15%' OR outbound_packet LIKE '%15%' OR package_dimentions LIKE '%15%' OR package_weight LIKE '%15%' OR delivered_package LIKE '%15%' OR safeguard_time LIKE '%15%' OR batch_number LIKE '%15%' OR barcode_packet LIKE '%15%')
  Rendered packages/_paginate.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered packages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 70ms (Views: 42.4ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
```

But no errors, or data in the view...

On Client model I have the same code and works fine, of course I only have to change the fields for client model.

Any idea why doesn't render nothing in the view?

**Update:**

*Added:* logger.debug "packages variable = #{@packages}"

```
Started GET "/clients/1/packages?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=13&commit=Buscar" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-28 17:29:06 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by PackagesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"13", "commit"=>"Buscar", "client_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Client Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  `clients`.* FROM `clients` WHERE `clients`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
packages variable = #<Package::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x00563c0eaf9c90>
  Rendered packages/_search.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Package Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `packages`.* FROM `packages` WHERE `packages`.`client_id` = 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `packages` WHERE `packages`.`client_id` = 1 AND (entry_packet LIKE '%13%' OR outbound_packet LIKE '%13%' OR package_dimentions LIKE '%13%' OR package_weight LIKE '%13%' OR delivered_package LIKE '%13%' OR safeguard_time LIKE '%13%' OR batch_number LIKE '%13%' OR barcode_packet LIKE '%13%')
  Rendered packages/_paginate.html.erb (2.1ms)
  Rendered packages/index.html.erb within layouts/application (26.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 391ms (Views: 312.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
```

Comment: That looks like the view for the search action.  In your server output it mentions a packages/_paginate.html.erb  What is in that file?  Add to the log by http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger `logger.debug "packages variable = #{@packages}"`

Comment: @AndyGauge packages/_packages.html.erb is a partial, contains what I put in the view, the search form.

Comment: I goofed, that should have been `@packages.inspect`  maybe put a `@packages.count`  I was trying to show how you can debug a controller.